# Help with a (possibly) dying cherry tree sapling

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, cherries

So I planted this tree sapling about 6 months ago when it was only 10cm. Spring quickly came and it really began to grow.

All looked well until recently where I noticed the newer leafs becoming discoloured as shown in the photo. Over the last couple weeks it has been getting progressively worse.

I’ve noticed ants are frequently at the base of the leafs, surrounding the red bulges. Moving on to the red bulges, I only noticed these when the discolouration of the leaves began but that could just because I actually started looking at the sapling at this point.

Either way, I know almost nothing about plants and this was supposed to be my baby step into it. Any advice as to what is going on and how to help the plant would be really appreciated.[image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: The UK, London.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't worry about the red bumps on the leaf stems; these are nectaries and they are meant to be there. You may notice ants visiting them because the nectar they produce is meant to attract some beneficial insects as part of the tree's defence against other insect invaders. They are not what is causing the problem with the leaves.Second, your tree is not currently dying!

On the subject of the new leaves, I can't quite tell if there are aphids present from the photograph - check under the leaves to see if there's any there, because they look as if aphids might be an issue. Aphids can be black, white green and sometimes brownish and they look like tiny flies -you may need a magnifying glass to inspect thoroughly. Ants on the plant (other than visiting the nectaries) also may indicate an aphid infestation, because the ants harvest the honeydew  the aphids produce.

Otherwise, the weather has been hot for the time of year (especially here in London) as well as very dry; your tree will need at least a couple of litres of water poured round the base about every 5 days until the weather breaks and rain returns. Ongoing be sure to keep it watered during dry spells - young trees need to be kept supplied with water during spring and summer for the first two years,until they have put out a good root system to seek out their own. If you have not yet given the tree any balanced fertiliser, do so now - something like Growmore granules sprinkled round the base and very lightly raked in will do the job.

Information on cherry tree problems here https://www.gardenfocused.co.uk/fruitarticles/cherry/pest-disease.php